# sum amounts obtained in foreach

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing something similar to a cart, in the database I have price and quantity, then I get the amount multiplying the price by the quantity, how do I add the result of all the multiplications?

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product['price'].'<br>';
    echo $product['quantity'].'<br>';
    $subtotal = $product['price']*$product['quantity'];
    echo $subtotal.'<br>';

    echo $total; //??????
}
?>
```

Suppose I have 5 products, then I have 5 subtotals, how do I add them to get the total?

Comment: `$subtotal += $product['price']*$product['quantity'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the total to accumulate over all the loops, so you define it outside the loop and add to it each time around:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $subtotal = $product['price']*$product['quantity'];
    $total += $subtotal;
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$total=0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product['price'].'<br>';
    echo $product['quantity'].'<br>';
    $subtotal = $product['price']*$product['quantity'];
    echo $subtotal.'<br>';

    $total=$total+$subtotal; //add here echo after loop ends
}
echo $total;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid looping you can use a few array functions to do it all.
I use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get price and quantity to separate arrays.
Then I use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to multiply the values with each other and [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to sum the multiplied values.

```
$price = array_column($products, "price");
$quantity = array_column($products, "quantity");

$total = array_sum(array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; },
               $price, $quantity));
Echo $total;
```

Or if you don't mind having code that is more or less unreadable this one liner will do the same.

```
$total = array_sum(array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x * $y; },
               array_column($products, "price"), array_column($products, "quantity")));
```